# count rows split by type for many csv files R

Tags: r

I have many csv files and I need to count the number of rows split by type. An example csv format is

```
Type,speed
Turtle,10
Lion,50
Cheetah,100
Turtle,12
Lion,70
Cheetah,110
Cheetah,170
```

So the example output would be:

```
Type count
turtle 2
lion 2
cheetah 3
```

I can do this for an individual file using the below R code:

```
library(dplyr)
##
a1 <- read.csv("data1.csv")
a1 %>% 
  group_by(Type, Type) %>% 
  summarise(count=n())
```

Can someone help me loop this across all csv files? I have `data1.csv` to `data100.csv`.

Comment: Are all of these files in the same directory, and if so, are they the *only* files in that directory?

Comment: Use `file_list<-list.files(directory, pattern=".csv")` to get a list of your csv files and then loop into your list (e.g. `for (file in file_list){ a1<-read.csv(file)...}`) or use `lapply` on the list with your function

Comment: Yes they are all in the same directory and are the only files in that directory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can use `list.files` to get a list of the files in your directory:

```
file_list <- list.files(directory) # pattern omitted since they're the only files
```

Then read all files into a list:

```
files <- lapply(file_list, read.csv, header=TRUE)
names(files) <- sub("\\.csv$", "", file_list)
```

Now, you could do:

```
res <- lapply(files, function(dat) dplyr::count(dat, Type))
```